# DNS name not resolved

Tags: dns

We have a server machine with IP address = 192.168.90.6. On this machine we have installed DNS and Domain Controller and DNS is integrated with AD (ad.corp.com).

Case 1: When machine joins with ad.corp.com, then there is no issue.
Case 2: When machine doesn't join with ad.corp.com, then problem happens, i.e. we cannot access domain machine by using its name. But when IP address is used, it works properly.

I want to know how we can change the setting of DNS Server to resolve Case 2 issue?

Result of `nslookup` on client machine is as per below:

```
C:\Users\abc>nslookup - 192.168.90.6

Default Server:  UnKnown
Address:  192.168.90.6

> dc1
Server:  UnKnown
Address:  192.168.90.6

*** UnKnown can't find dc1: Server failed
```

Answer (score 1):

0)

> ad.corp.com

The [corp.com](http://corp.com/) domain is owned by Mike O'Connor who isn't currently using it for much. If you are also using that domain internally you have a recipe for future confusion when Mike sells it to someone or starts using it in earnest (or even now).

---

1)

```
Default Server:  UnKnown
Address:  192.168.90.6
```

Your DNS server at 192.168.90.6 doesn't know who it is! 
It lacks a PTR record in a 192.168.90 zonefile

```
6   IN   PTR   dc1.example.com.
```

or MS equivalent.

I recommend you register a domain for your company and use it internally using a split-horizon DNS setup. Or pay a consultant to advise.

---

2)

```
> dc1 
Server:  UnKnown   
Address:  192.168.90.6  

*** UnKnown can't find dc1: Server failed
```

Your DNS server has no idea what DNS domain to append to incomplete queries

---

These are all fairly fundamental issues suggesting that whoever set this up needs more training or to call in a consultant.

Comment: Thanks RedGrittyBrick for you reply,
I want to clear my issue again so that you know the exact problem.

When my client machine Joined with domain ad.corp.com then nslookup result is as per below

C:\Users\abc>nslookup - 192.168.90.6
Default Server:  UnKnown
Address:  192.168.90.6

> dc1
Server:  UnKnown
Address:  192.168.90.6

Name:    dc1.ad.acty-sys.co.in
Address:  192.168.90.225

Comment: BUT when I UNJOINED Client machine with domain ad.corp.com then 
it gives following result

.....

> dc1
Server:  UnKnown
Address:  192.168.90.6

*** UnKnown can't find dc1: Server failed

I am facing this problem, hope you understand my problem. 
Please kindly help me for the same.

Answer (score 0):

You should configure your "DNS Server's IP" as prefered DNS Server at your un-joined client first. It should work.

Comment: Thanks Rajendra for your reply

I have configured my client machine with DNS Server's IP as prefered DNS server 
but still it is not working. 

Result of nslookup is same as above.

Comment: @Acty System: - Please perform a cross check that, Did you created associate PTR records in DNS Server? and please use Server's FQDN for accessing it from outsite or unjoined clients. Such as : - (dc1.example.local)